# Active class for internal links

Tags: html, jsp, href

I have these 4 tabs

```
<div class="tslcNav" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="mngPost.html">Manage Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="riskAssesment.html">Risk Assessment</a></li>
            <li><a href="security_setup.html">Security Setup</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to write the code for following condition

```
if(a href="addProduct.html") then make href="mngPost.html" class as active
```

So that it will give active class(color for that tab). That means whenever I am on `addProduct.html` page then `mngPost.html` tab must be active.I want to write this code in `jsp`.